# cannot infer type arguments for EntityModel<>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I am trying to upgrade spring boot from 2.1.6 to 2.6.6, The hateoas component has also been upgraded. I have renamed the class names as well using the migrate script. But in the code I am getting the below error while returning.

cannot infer type arguments for EntityModel<>

Code:

```
@Override
public EntityModel<T> toModel(T entity) {
    if (this.controller == null && StringUtils.hasLength(this.rel))
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("test");

    return new EntityModel<>(entity,
            linkTo(methodOn(this.controller).one(entity.getId())).withSelfRel();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to roll back to spring-boot 2.5. Then resolve all the deprecations, then move to spring-boot 2.6.
You will find the constructor has changed:
new EntityModel<> is now: EntityModel.of()